# Noscript to redirect (I need to redirect)

Tags: javascript, noscript

I want to disallow access to my website when the user does not have Javascript. I do not with to simply display a message. How would I go about doing this? None of the other questions are quite the same in the sense of disallowing access.

Something like this:

```
<noscript>
Redirect to another page.
</noscript>
```

But I've seen that this is not good to do? I repeat though, I do not simply want to display a message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You may try this:-

```
<noscript>
<a href="">Click here to continue</a>
</noscript>
```

or

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=noscript.html">
</noscript>
```

Comment: <noscript>
<?php header("Location: $url"); ?>
</noscript>

Comment: @Nadia, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an solution from another post. 
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">`

Answer (score 1):

1. Have your landing page be your NON-JavaScript warning page.
2. Include a peice of JavaScript called from `onload` to re-direct to your REAL page (where you assume the end-user has JavaScript).

Comment: This would slow down the process for an average user though. I see what you're thinking though.

Comment: So would META HTTP-EQUIV based refresh. There's a downside to everything.

Comment: Would you be able to explain why META HTTP-EQUIV would too?

Comment: In the general case it's it also exhibits a delay. By putting it in `<noscript>` you limit its effects to NON-JavaScript browsers.

Comment: @KriiV:- There are two drawbacks for META refresh tags:- **1** If a page redirects too quickly (less than 2-3 seconds), using the "Back" button on the next page may cause some browsers to move back to the redirecting page, whereupon the redirect will occur again. This is bad for usability, as this may cause a reader to be "stuck" on the last website.

Comment: @KriiV:- **2** A reader may or may not want to be redirected to a different page, which can lead to user dissatisfaction or raise concerns about security. Check this out:- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh#Drawbacks